# How Should I get the images in base64 format in other input fields?

Tags: javascript, html, input, base64, image-upload

Actually, I am making an app that can take user images and then upload them to the server but it throws an error when I upload more than one file. I want to take 5 files and then convert them into base64 URL and then insert it into the server.

In the following code, I want to take the images uploaded by the user. Then convert each image into base64code and then set the value of each input as the base64code of each image respectively.

```js
formImg.onchange = evt => {
var file = formImg.files
  if (file) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(file.item(1)); 
     reader.onloadend = function() {
     var base64data = reader.result;
    document.getElementById('Img').value = base64data ;
    }
  }
}
formImg.onchange = evt => {
  const [file] = formImg.files
  if (file) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(file.item(2)); 
     reader.onloadend = function() {
     var base64data = reader.result;
    document.getElementById('Img2').value = base64data ;
    }
  }
}
formImg.onchange = evt => {
  const [file] = formImg.files
  if (file) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(file.item(3)); 
     reader.onloadend = function() {
     var base64data = reader.result;
    document.getElementById('Img3').value = base64data ;
    }
  }
}
formImg.onchange = evt => {
  const [file] = formImg.files
  if (file) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(file.item(4)); 
     reader.onloadend = function() {
     var base64data = reader.result;
    document.getElementById('Img4').value = base64data ;
    }
  }
}
formImg.onchange = evt => {
  const [file] = formImg.files
  if (file) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(file.item(5)); 
     reader.onloadend = function() {
     var base64data = reader.result;
    document.getElementById('Img5').value = base64data ;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form  action="" method="POST">
  <div id="1" class="mb-3">
  <label for="formImg" class="form-label bg-white text-dark ">Upload 1st Image : </label>
  <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formImg" name="formImg"multiple required > 
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Img" name="Img"    style="">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Img2" name="Img2"    style="">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Img3" name="Img3"    style="">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Img4" name="Img4"    style="">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Img5" name="Img5"    style="">
 </div> 
  <br>
  <button type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' class="btn btn-primary mb-2" style="" onclick="refresh()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> The error message is: 
> Uncaught TypeError: file.item is not a function
> at HTMLInputElement.formImg.onchange

Comment: Why do you want to use base64 anyway?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are capture multiple event instead of one is the rout issue, adjust your javascript code like this:

```
var read_base64 = function(file, element_id){
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
   reader.onloadend = function() {
   var base64data = reader.result;
   document.getElementById(element_id).value = base64data ;
};
formImg.onchange = evt => {
        var file = formImg.files
          if (file) {
        if( file.length > 0 ){
             read_base64 (file.item(0), 'Img1'); 
        }
        if( file.length > 1 ){
             read_base64 (file.item(1), 'Img2'); 
        }
        if( file.length > 2 ){
             read_base64 (file.item(2), 'Img3'); 
        }
        if( file.length > 3 ){
             read_base64 (file.item(3), 'Img4'); 
        }
        if( file.length > 4 ){
             read_base64 (file.item(4), 'Img5'); 
        }
       }
    }
```